# Perl: Print Hash value with newline

Tags: perl, hash, newline

I have a hash. The value for the key in hash is concatenation of 2 strings. (`$value1 and $value2`) 
When I print the value of concatenated variable `$values` it prints with the newline. 
But when I am printing it in html table format the newline doesn't exist. How can I have the newline retained.

```
 my $value1 = "Good files are 272 :10%";
 my $value2 = "Bad files are 300 : 15%";
 my $values = $value1 . $value2; 
 print "values : $values ";

 # HASH with multiple values for each key
 my %hash ;
 $keyvalue = "foobar";
 $hash{$keyvalue} =  $values ;     

# SET UP THE TABLE
print "<table border='1'>";
print "<th>Category</th><th>value</th>";    

#Print key and values in hash in tabular format
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
   print "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
   print "<td>".$hash{$key}."</td>";
}
```

*** Current Output: *** 
It prints the hash values without newline

```
values : Good files are 272 :10%
Bad files are 300 : 15%

Category Value
foobar   Good files are 272 :10%Bad files are 300 : 15%
```

*** Desired Output: ***

```
 Category Value
 foobar   Good files are 272 :10%
          Bad files are 300 : 15%
```

Comment: The first four lines of code, cannot output the first two lines of output as you mentioned, in fact it will output: "values : $values Good files are 272 :10%Bad files are 300 : 15%" ... How does it outputs these two strings separated them by a newline despite that there is no newline character in the first string? This is impossible based on your code ! I think your example is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, you use the `<br>` element to create a new line. Therefore, just do a search and replace -- replace any line breaks in your input with `<br>`.

Since you're concatenating `$value1` and `$value2`, you can do this:

```
$values = $value1 . '<br>' . $value2;
```